# <merge> tag as Root element not displaying view properly?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

If I place the <**merge**> as my root element for my child views, it is not displayed on API 19, 15 as I checked but it do display on API 26 though the views are overlapped, what the actual issue?

Before I was using <**FrameLayout**>, and I got a Lint warning to replace it with <**merge**> tag.

In the Code snippet nothing is displayed on API 15, 19 but on API 26 it displays both TextViews in overlapped function, what's the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"/>

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="world"/>

</merge>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve??

Comment: @mzeus.bolt Actually I had a layout whose root was <merge> and has three child elements viz, RecyclerView, TextView and a ProgressBar. So when my RecycleView was unable to display lists, TextView displayed the error message otherwise textview was invisible, this behaviour works fine on API 26, but nothing displays on API 19, 15.